# Nested Horizontal Menu updatable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want make a 2-level horizontal menu updatable. I will have available the data previously loaded (php) and I want create this "effect". I sure this exists but I don't found anything using my mother language or searching in english.

My data structure is like this:

```
MainElement1,
    SecondItem1Name -> SecondItem1Image
    SecondItem2Name -> SecondItem2Image
    SecondItem3Name -> SecondItem3Image
MainElement2,
    SecondItem1Name -> SecondItem1Image
    SecondItem2Name -> SecondItem2Image
```

This my desired result:

[image]

- First Row: Main menu Items (I will have it in a PHP Array)
- Second Row: Elements associateds in the selected item in first row.
- Third Row: Not in the top image, but was a second row item image.

My question about this. There are popular menu that allows make this? Its better than I create this from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to you. If you enjoy the experience of coding with JavaScript and CSS then definitely feel free to make it yourself. However, you might find that it is easier to use a template. In fact, you can do it entirely using CSS.

Try out this link and see if it's what you're looking for. Basically you're going to use a ul and then nested lis and uls and style those elements with padding animations in your CSS to create the effect.